# Why are there missing prices for 1981-04-17?

Tags: historical-data, yahoofinance, missing-values

I was going over historical prices in Yahoo Finance, when I noticed that AAPL and IBM have no prices for 1981-04-17. I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. Why are the prices missing?
2. In the future, how can I answer such historical anomaly questions? Searching the date and "finance" or "market" in Google didn't give anything interesting.

Thanks.

Comment: @nbbo2 that's the answer!  Perhaps convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following link the stock exchanges were closed on 1981/04/17 due to Good Friday, a major Christian holiday whose date varies from year to year but is generally in March or April.

http://nyseholidays.blogspot.com/2012/11/nyse-holidays-from-1981-1990.html

In general if 2 major stocks are missing (or even better if the SP500 index ^SPX is missing) on a given day you should suspect a holiday.